# Adding charts to OpenGeo suite SDK

Tags: openlayers-2, geoext, boundless-suite, graph, chart

I just wanted to gauge the work flow for adding charts to a map using the SDK that comes with OpenGeo suite. I know it seems a vague question I'm just trying to get my head around it :/

So far the documentation is pretty straight forward with adding plugins using the gxp.plugins such as  * @require plugins/FeatureEditor.js

However Im not sure about how I would go about adding geoEXT additions such as [Link from OpenGeo Suite to GeoEXT charts](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/#sample-3). What would the basic starting point be, and any pointers would be great. I will eventually be looking to integrate into a popup on my map a graph, that would take values over a time frame and plot them.